# How to make Laravel unique validation work on an input array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

**UpdateEntityRequest.php**:

```
'phones'          => 'sometimes|nullable|array',
'phones.*.id'     => 'sometimes|required|integer|distinct|exists:entity_phones,id,entity_id,'.$this->id,
'phones.*.number' => 'required|alpha_num|max:255|distinct|unique:entity_phones,number,'.$this->id.',entity_id',
```

***entity_phones table***:

```
id, number, entity_id.
unique constraint: (number, entity_id)
```

**EntityRepository.php**:

```
foreach ($attributes['phones'] as $phone) {
    if (isset($phone['id'])) {
        $entity->phones()->updateOrCreate([
            'id'         => $phone['id'],
            'entity_id'  => $entity->id
        ], $phone);
    } else {
        $entity->phones()->create($phone);
    }
}
```

My entity can have more than phone associated, but not a repeated number. My intention is to check the unique (entity_id, number) in the **UpdateEntityRequest.php** so:

- If the phone object comes without an id, it should check that the combination of number, entity_id doesn't exists. But the number can exist with other entity_id.
- If the request comes with an id, it should check that the combination of number, entity_id doesn't exists only in other ids, but ignore the given id.

I'm having trouble witht the Laravel Unique rule validating only when i want it to make the validation. Any ideas how could I make this solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
$phoneIds = $this->input('phones.*.id');

'phones.*.number' =>
                    [
                        'required_with:phones',
                        'alpha_num',
                        'max:255',
                        'distinct',
                        Rule::unique('entity_phones', 'number')
                        ->where('entity_id', $this->id)
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($phoneIds) {
                            return $query->where('id', '!=', array_shift($phoneIds));
                        })
                    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ignore a given ID during the unique check try using the Rule class to fluently define the rule.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($request_data, [
    'number' => [
        'required',
        'alpha_num', (...all your other rules)
        Rule::unique('entity_phones')->ignore($entity_id),
    ],
]);
```

You can read more in laravel docs about [unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) in paragraph: Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID.